# How can I access a specific column from Spark Data frame in python?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My Dataframe looks like this

```
------+-------+                                                                
|cat_id|counter|
+------+-------+
|    12|  61060|
|     1| 542118|
|    13| 164700|
|     3| 406622|
|     5|  54902|
|    10| 118281|
|    11|  13658|
|    14|  72229|
|     2| 131206|
+------+-------+
```

Query to get above data frame is :

`grouped_data = dataframe.groupBy("cat_id").agg(count("*").alias("counter"))`

Now I need to read values for different cat_id to save it in another database.

The way I can get it done is by using a for loop on my id's

```
for cat_id in cat_ids_map:
     statsCount = grouped_data.select("counter").filter("cat_id = " + cat_id).collect()[0].counter
```

But I think there can be a better way to read the counter without for loop. Any suggestions would be helpful!!!

Thanks

Comment: what is your target database ? you can [write](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter) your dataframe almost anywhere.

Comment: Need to pass it to influxDB for logging purposes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're to iterate through the entire dataframe, the way to do it is usually using a **.foreach** function.

so you would do:

```py
grouped_data.foreach(lambda x: f(x))
```

where **f** is your function that will do whatever you want with each element in the dataframe